# All the data of First form are not storing at Backend(ReserveRoomsBackend.php) file

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

Problem Statement:All the data of First form are not getting into the backend file(ReserveRoomsBackend.php) which include start_date, end_date,sr_citizen_choice which may be loosing at between of program so on submitting it is not passed to another page so what should be the solution for this .

IN Reserve.html file i have used two files

1.findReserveRoomsBackend.php is the file in which it will find out the free rooms and return a single room and the respective building

I think that when the findReserveRoomsBackend.php return the room number then dates are lost

2.ReserveRoomsBackend.php file for mysql connectivity and insert the data of form into the  MYSQL database.

The following is the Reserve.html file

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("form_reserve").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("label").style.display = "none";
   });

   function doAjaxPost(){

        var from_date = document.getElementById("from_date").value;
        var end_date = document.getElementById("end_date").value;
        var no_of_males= document.getElementById("id_males").value;
        var no_of_females=document.getElementById("id_females").value;
        var no_of_childrens=document.getElementById("id_childrens").value;
            var sr_citizen ;
        for (var i=0; i < document.reserve_rooms.sr_citizen_choice.length; i++) 
                        {
                  if (document.reserve_rooms.sr_citizen_choice[i].checked) 
                                 {
                var sr_citizen =                                 document.reserve_rooms.sr_citizen_choice[i].value;
                     }
               }

        //.getJSON -- get building id, building name, room number 
        // if building id > 0 show the reservation details form
        // else show the messgae

//findReserveRoomsBackend.php is the file in which it will find out the free rooms and //return a single room and the respective building
//I think that when the findReserveRoomsBackend.php return the room number then dates are //lost

//findReserveRoomsBackend.php file for mysql connectivity and insert the date of form into the  MYSQL database

var link = 'http://localhost/findReserveRoomsBackend.php?start_date='+from_date+' & end_date='+end_date+' & sr_citizen_choice='+sr_citizen+' & no_of_males='+no_of_males+'& no_of_females='+no_of_females+' & no_of_childrens='+no_of_childrens;

        $.getJSON(link,function(json)
       {
            if( json.length> 0)
       {

document.form_reserve.action ="http://localhost/ReserveRoomsBackend.php?        bldg_number="+json[0].bldg_number +" & room_number="+json[0].room_number;
        document.getElementById("form_reserve").style.display = "block";
    }
             else
       {
           document.getElementById("label").style.display = "block";
       }

alert("inside json finction " + json.length+"  "+json[0].room_number+"   "+json[0].bldg_number);
        }); //.getJSON

    }//doAjaxPost

</script>

<div style="width: 950px; height: 500px; background-color: #FAE89E; border-width: 3px; border-style: inset; color: #FF0000; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial; overflow: auto;">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker.js"> </script>
<body>
```

------This is the First form---------------------------------------------------------------

```
<form id='target'  METHOD="POST" name='reserve_rooms'>

    <p> From Date:<input name="from"   type="text" id ="from_date"/>
        End Date:<input name="to" type="text"   id="end_date" />

   Senior Citizen*:<input type  = "radio" name  = "sr_citizen_choice" value = "Y" />Yes  
                   <input type  = "radio" name  = "sr_citizen_choice" value = "N"  checked  />No

<input  id="find_availability" type="button" value="Find Availability" onClick="doAjaxPost()"  />
        </p>

    </form> 


    <div id='label' name ='label'>
           No Rooms are available for the given period 
    </div>
```

--This is the second form-----------------------------------

```
<form id='form_reserve' name='form_reserve' " METHOD="POST">

<fieldset>

    <legend>Personal Details :</legend>

        <b>Name*:</b> <input type="text" name="fname"  /> 
                Address*:<input type="text" size=50 width=30 name="faddress"/>
                City*:<input type="text" name="fcity" />
        State*:</b> <input type="text" name="fstate" />
        Country*:<select name="gourl" size="1">
          <option>India</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Reserve Room"/>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are those the only two of the GET variables not showing up in your backend file?  I don't see any input field on your form with an ID of 'from_date' or 'end_date'

Comment: please repost your question. be specific and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is all the same HTML file I assume?

If so, you have two  opening tags and only one closing  tag. The first  (above your date fields) has an invalid method attribute ('button'). The second one will actually create a proper form which is presumably what is being submitted.

So get rid of your first  tag and move the second one above your date fields.

Secondly, the field names that are submitted come from the 'name' attribute not the 'id', so your date fields need to have name="start_date" and name="end_date"

Finally, it is a POST form so you will find your posted variables in PHP in $_POST not $_GET. You can also find them in $_REQUEST, although personally I think it's more secure if you specify in your code where you expect user-supplied variables to come from, so use $_POST.

Hope this answers it!

Comment: i have made the changes but still it is not solved and now i have explain the problem more clearly please again see it and post the solution.